# > Directory ......sdk\build\outputs\aar\sdk-release.aar' specified for property 'inputDirectory' is not a directory

Tags: android, gradlew

When I want to create an .aar file,this problem was happend.

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> ```

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':sdk:countReleaseDexMethods'.
> Directory 'D:\Android_develop\andisu_chengyunshang1031\carrier\branches\dev\platforms\android\WeexFrameworkWrapper\sdk\build\outputs\aar\sdk-release.aar' specified for property 'inputDirectory' is not a directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Answer (score 0):

In my sdk's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.7.3'
        classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin:0.5.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.github.hierynomus.license" version "0.14.0"
}
......
```

Fixed:
  Note out plugins can help you fix this problem:

```
 // classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.7.3'
 // apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```